# Excel VBA Autofiltering

Tags: vba, excel

I am having difficulty getting autofiltering to work using VBA.  My code works once, afterwards I get a runtime error code 91.  Here is my code.  I know it is simple, but what am I missing?  Thanks in advance.

```
Dim MyWorksheet As Worksheet
Set MyWorksheet = Sheets("entity details - cost summary")
Sheets("entity details - cost summary").Select
Range("H6").Select
MyWorksheet.AutoFilter.sort.SortFields.Clear
MyWorksheet.AutoFilter.sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("H6"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
    xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
With MyWorksheet.AutoFilter. _
    sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Update:
The error occurs on line 5

```
MyWorksheet.AutoFilter.sort.SortFields.Clear
```

Row 5 are column headers, from column B through P.  Each row represents a different piece of manufacturing equipment, and each column represents a different attribute or cost.  Column H has possible entries.  So I am trying to use auto-filter to group each of those entries.

Comment: which line throws the error?

Comment: The easiest way to work with the [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is by defining a range and working with it inside a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). The [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) is good for this. However, it is difficult to write to that method without seeing what your data looks like since you are starting on row 6 and have offered no indication what surrounds H6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work on the range of data in columns B:P starting with a header row in row 5 and continuing on to the last value in column B.

```
Sub equip_sort()
    With Worksheets("entity details - cost summary")
        With .Range(.Cells(5, 2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count, 15)
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(7), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
                .Columns(7).AutoFilter field:=1
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The data gets sorted and a filter column is selected (column H). No filter is applied as nothing in that area has been specified and no sample data or expected results have been provided.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped that worked wonderfully.  I appreciate the approach, I will be to study and replicate.  No additional filtering was necessary.  Apologies that my update had an unfortunate omission - column H has _three_ possible entries.  So once I put the three in order I am able to more easily work with the data.